# How to get the Role Name of the current user? (WordPress)

Tags: users, user-roles, bbpress

I currently have this snippet:

```
$user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id()); 
echo $user->roles[1];
```

and the output the slug of the bbPress forum role. 
(roles[0] would be the general WP role but I don't need that.)

What I need is the role **name**, not the slug. 
So, the expected output should be something like "Keymaster", "Participant", "Spectator" etc.

So, how do I get the Role Name of the current user?

Comment: The function `wp_get_current_user()` should helps you. You get return all data to the user via the class ´WP_User`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if bbPress follows WordPress conventions, but WP has a global class called [`$WP-roles`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_roles/) that holds the role information. So, starting from what you have, there is the role of the current user:

```
$current_role = $user->roles[1];
```

Next, retrieve a list of all roles:

```
$all_roles = $wp_roles->roles;
```

Then, loop through `$all_roles` and find the `$current_role"`:

```
foreach ($all_roles as $role_key => $role_details) {
  if ($role_key == $current_role) $current_role_name = $role_details['name'];
  }
```

Now, `$current_role_name` should hold the display name you're looking for (I didn't check this code, however).

Comment: The result is a warning that says: **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: I don't use bbPress, so I don't know if it does something to the roles structure. If you use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) on `$all_roles` you should be able to see its structure and adapt the `foreach` loop with the right arguments.

Answer (score 2):

thnx for this code snippet! I'm running a Buddypress install (and custom theme) where it is possible to add multiple roles to one user. I adjusted your code a little bit for that to work:

```
<?php
//Get role name by user ID
if( !function_exists('get_user_role_name') ){
    function get_user_role_name($user_ID){
    global $wp_roles;

        $user_data = get_userdata($user_ID);
        $user_role_slug = $user_data->roles;

        foreach($user_role_slug as $user_role){
            //count user role nrs
            $user_role_nr++;
            //add comma separation of there is more then one role 
            if($user_role_nr > 1) { $user_role_list .= ", "; }
            //add role name 
            $user_role_list .= translate_user_role($wp_roles->roles[$user_role]['name']);
        }

    //return user role list
    return $user_role_list;

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they've already solved this issue. But, now I just wrote this and I decided to share it.

```
<?php
//Get role name by user ID
if( !function_exists('get_user_role_name') ){
    function get_user_role_name($user_ID){
        global $wp_roles;

        $user_data = get_userdata($user_ID);
        $user_role_slug = $user_data->roles[0];
        return translate_user_role($wp_roles->roles[$user_role_slug]['name']);
    }
}
?>

<?php echo get_user_role_name(User ID here);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current user role name(translatable name but not slug) by following function, you just need to pass current user role slug as a parameter:

```
function wp_get_current_user_translatable_role_name( $current_user_role_slug = '' ) {
    $role_name = '';

    if ( ! function_exists( 'get_editable_roles' ) ) {
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php';
    }

    // Please note that translate_user_role doesn't work in the front-end currently.
    load_textdomain( 'default', WP_LANG_DIR . '/admin-' . get_locale() . '.mo' );

    $editable_roles = array_reverse( get_editable_roles() );

    foreach ( $editable_roles as $role => $details ) {
        $name = translate_user_role( $details['name'] );
        // preselect specified role
        if ( $current_user_role_slug == $role ) {
            $role_name  = $name;
        }
    }

    echo $role_name ;
}
```

Now, get current user role slug name by following code:

```
$user_meta = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
$current_user_role_slug = $user_meta->roles[0];
```

Use `wp_get_current_user_translatable_role_name( $current_user_role_slug );` function to get current user role name(translatable name but not slug).

NOTE: User must have to login to view role name.

Comment: Quotation: "What I need is the role **name**, not the slug. "

Comment: @nmr you can just echo variable name like that: `<?php echo ucfirst($role_name); ?>` this should output like "Keymaster", "Participant", "Spectator", "administrator" etc.

Comment: But it's still a `slug`. What if the role will be like `slug='spectator_vip' name= 'VIP Spectator'` or `slug= 'shop_manager' name= 'Shop Manager'`. If user has a role  "editor" (slug of built in role), in the user list, depending on the active language, you can see "Editor", "Redaktor", "редактор". You can not assume that the name is equal to the slug.

Comment: @nmr see my modified code, i just misunderstand the point of question but now i understand the point and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to get it

```
function get_user_role($user_id) {
    global $wp_roles;

    $roles = array();
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
    foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
        $roles[] .= translate_user_role( $role );
    }
    return implode(', ',$roles);
} 
//then call the function with userid param
echo get_user_role( 7 );
```

Comment: The code in its current form tries to translate **slug**, which is a poor solution. You should pass role name to function `translate_user_role()`.